# How to find the fraction of time spent in each state of a periodic Markov chain

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, markov-chains, markov-process

Consider a Markov chain (e.g. 2x2 or 3x3) which is **periodic**, therefore there is no stationary distribution for the chain.

What is the way to find the fraction of time spent in each state by the system?

If it was possible to define a stationary distribution $\Pi$ I would have said that  the fraction of time spent by the system in the state j is:$$f_j =\Pi_j$$

But in the case of periodic chain $\Pi$ is not defined, so what is the right way to get $f_j$?

Comment: Why do periodic chains not have stationary distributions?

Comment: @kimchilover I think because if the transition matrix is $W$, it could be that $\lim_{n\to \infty} W^n$ does not exist. Is this wrong? Is it possible to find $\Pi$ anyway?

Comment: The matrix $W=\pmatrix{0&1\\1&0}$ is the transition matrix of a periodic MC, but has $(1/2,1/2)$ as a stationary distribution even though $W^n$ does not converge to a limit.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I don't think the chain you suggested has a stationary distribution, as it is explained in the answer to this question https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/152139/markov-chains-with-a-stationary-distribution-but-no-limiting-distribution , in particular :

"The usual definition of limiting distribution is that a Markov chain has a limiting distribution $\Pi$ if **for every** initial distribution $P(0)$,

$$\lim_{n\to \infty} P(0) P^n=\Pi$$"

Comment: Of course this chain does not have a limiting distribution.   But (by thing 4 of the page you quoted) is does have a stationary distribution.

Comment: And, look at the ANSWER to the question you cited, which gives the same example I did.